# 502 Error: Bad Gateway on Azure App Service with IronPDF

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, ironpdf

I am attempting to get IronPDF working on my deployment of an ASP.NET Core 3.1 App Service.
I am not using Azure Functions for any of this, just a regular endpoints on an Azure App Service -which, when a user calls it, the service generates and returns a generated PDF document.

When running the endpoint on localhost, it works perfectly- generating the report from the HTML passed into the method. However, once I deploy it to my Azure Web App Service, I am getting a *502 - Bad Gateway* error, as attached (displayed in Swagger for neatness sake).

[image]

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> AgencyDownload([FromBody] AgencyReportSubmissionDto filters)
{
  var user = await _userService.GetUserByIdAsync(HttpContext.User.GetUserId());

  // Generate the PDF
  var content = await _agencyReport.Generate(user, null, filters.FilterDate, filters.Content, filters.Type);

  // Return the PDF to the browser
  return new FileContentResult(content.BinaryData, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = "report.pdf" };
}
```

**Service:**

```
public async Task<PdfDocument> Generate(User user, byte[] letterhead, DateTimeOffset filterDate, string html, AgencyReportTypes reportType)
{
   var corporateIdentity = new CorporateIdentity()
   {
        PrimaryColor = "#000000",
        PrimaryTextColor = "#ffffff",
        SecondaryColor = "#ffffff"
   };

    // Inserts the HTML content (from form) into the HTML template
    var htmlContent = Template(corporateIdentity.PrimaryColor, corporateIdentity.PrimaryTextColor).Replace("{{HtmlContent}}", html);
        
    TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("South Africa Standard Time");
    var convertedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(filterDate.UtcDateTime, tz);
    var Renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();

    Renderer.RenderingOptions.Title = "Agency Report - for " + convertedDate.ToString("d MMMM yyyy");
    Renderer.RenderingOptions.PaperSize = IronPdf.Rendering.PdfPaperSize.A4;

    var doc = await Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync(htmlContent);
    return doc;
}
```

**Solution:**

I noticed that if I performed a manual deployment to that app service, it was working, but when I was deploying from my pipeline- I had the error above.

So I went snooping around my pipelines and upon changing it to this, it worked.

```
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: Deploy API Artifact
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                AzureSubscription: 'My-Azure-Subscription'
                enableCustomDeployment: true
                DeploymentType: 'zipDeploy'
                deployToSlotOrASE: true
                SlotName: 'development'
                AppType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'my-api'
                Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/API.zip'
                ResourceGroupName: 'MyResource'
```

the **'DeploymentType: 'zipDeploy'"** was key.

*Thanks to Alex Hanneman for pointing me in the right direction.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am also using Azure App Service as an API, wrapping IronPDF. Upgrading to latest Iron PDF package also broke my app, returning a 502.

What I did to fix it is deploy the code using ZipDeploy and then set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 0. This is also needed to get the Iron PDF log files to show up in Azure, as they recommend here: https://iron.helpscoutdocs.com/article/122-azure-log-files.

Comment: Disabling the 'Run from package file' option is also recommend on the main IronPDF website here: https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/azure/#the-golden-rule

Comment: This led me on the right track, though since I deploy my application using pipelines, I've had to simply add the attribute "deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'" to my artifact- in addition to changing my app service configuration as you've outlined. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Alex Hanneman - I am also facing the same issue/error with Iron PDF, We have deployed our Containerized  Asp.net Web API using Docker (Linux Image) in the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). Any guidance to resolve this issue with AKS?

Comment: This is the best solution for Windows Container on Azure. Works for me.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this worked for me too with regard to not finding files I want to render as even though it automatically knows it's a ZIP deployment, it doesn't check the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE and sets that to 1. Forcing it to choose zipDeploy doesn't change the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

We are also facing the same issue with iron PDF but while changing the type of deployment to zip it's solves.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

App Service runs your apps in a sandbox and most PDF libraries will fail.  Looking at the [IronPDF documentation](https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/azure/), they say that you can run it in a VM or a container. Since you already are using App Service, simply package your app in a container, publish it to a container registry and configure App Service to run it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will need to do a bit of research into doing all of that but I'll give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: I would suggest a Debian 10 Docker image as outline here: https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/docker-linux/